# Is this use of "most awarded" correct?

Tags: word-usage

I have heard the phrase "most awarded (car) in history" in many commercials for automobiles lately, and I wonder if it is being used correctly? Clearly, the advertiser means "the car that has received the most awards", but what I hear is "the car that is given as an award most often".  I suspect that the first is technically grammatically correct, but it grates on my ear.

Comment: I've never heard *most awarded* used of ***cars*** before, but Google Books claims [half-a-dozen written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22most+awarded+cars%22). And there are hundreds of instances of [*most awarded **films***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22most+awarded+films%22), so you can assume your version is at least "credible" even if it's relatively unfamiliar.

Comment: Top of the field this seems to aim at.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's very awkward and dumb.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit awkward but it certainly doesn't violate grammar. After all, it doesn't sound so strange if you change it to "most often awarded," right? And it's common to things like "he was the most decorated soldier in his platoon" - semantically, that's no different from "he was the most awarded soldier."